# How should i order by price in this case

Tags: php

I want to order by price. But I am getting the price from two different table and compare it to get the minimum price and print it if price is above `0`. It is also possible that price is present in only one database. The rough structure of my code is:

```
query1 = choose products

while = fetch the products details {

query2 = get the price1, order by price1
query3 = get the price2, order by price2

if statement to get the minimum price so price = minimum price

if (price>0) {
    echo product result
}

}
```

How can I order the result according to the price?

EDIT: Product is already selected, i want to acquire the price of products from two different price table

Comment: Why not one query that gets both products and price in one go, with an ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Do you want it in MySQL or in PHP? It can be done with a single MySQL query.

Comment: might be an idea to add a mysql tag, as your question is mysql related as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in just one query, much more efficiently:

```sql
SELECT `a`.*, LEAST(`b`.`price`,`c`.`price`) AS `price`
FROM `products` `a`
JOIN `price1` `b` ON `a`.`id`=`b`.`product_id`
JOIN `price2` `c` on `a`.`id`=`c`.`product_id`
WHERE `price`>0
ORDER BY `price` ASC
```

Adjust according to your database's tables and columns.

Comment: Product is already selected, i want to acquire the price of products from two different price table

Comment: @wiki Then use this query as part of your product select, and you won't have any problems with sorting by price